# How do I show the amount of true and falses?

Tags: java

How do I show the amount of True and falses. For example: 
True - 8 is divisible by 2.
True - 42 is divisible by 2.
False - 11 is not divisible by 2.
(What I Want to it to show...)
True: 2
False: 1

```
    Random r = new Random();

    int[] num = new int[3]; // same as "= {0,0,0,0,0}
    boolean gameResult = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        num[i] = r.nextInt(100) + 1;

        if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("TRUE - " + num[i] + " is divisible by 2.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("FALSE - " + num[i]
                    + " is not divisible by 2.");
            gameResult = false;
        }

    }

    if (gameResult) {
        System.out.println("You Won");

    } else {
        System.out.println("You Lost");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You could count them

Comment: @Typo As you can tell from my code I'm a complete newb to Java so can you please show me the code to count them?

Comment: It's not a code problem, if you did all this by yourself then you shouldn't have any problem figuring out what to do...it's like asking for someone to tie your shoes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Random r = new Random();

    int[] num = new int[3]; // same as "= {0,0,0,0,0}
    int tCount = 0, fCount = 0;
    boolean gameResult = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        num[i] = r.nextInt(100) + 1;

        if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("TRUE - " + num[i] + " is divisible by 2.");
            tCount++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("FALSE - " + num[i]
                    + " is not divisible by 2.");
            fCount++;
            gameResult = false;
        }

    }

    System.out.println("True:" + tCount + "False:" + fCount);

    if (gameResult) {
        System.out.println("You Won");

    } else {
        System.out.println("You Lost");
    }

}
}
```

The above code returns true and false counts. You can now use them as you want.

Comment: Awesome it worked! I just have one question... Why did you put tCount++ and fCount++?

Comment: tCount and fCount are 2 variables. Both are 0 at first. If the result is true, we are increasing the tCount by 1 and if the result is false, we are increasing the fCount by 1. These are used to just count no of trues and no of falses. Is it clear now.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the java code:**

```
import java.util.Random;

    public class DivisibleTest{

         public static void main(String []args){

          Random r = new Random();
          int counterTrue=0;
          int counterFalse=0;

        int[] num = new int[3]; // same as "= {0,0,0,0,0}
        boolean gameResult = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            num[i] = r.nextInt(100) + 1;

            if (num[i] % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("TRUE - " + num[i] + " is divisible by 2.");
                counterTrue++;
                counterTrue=counterTrue+1;
            } else {
                System.out.println("FALSE - " + num[i]
                        + " is not divisible by 2.");

                gameResult = false;
                System.out.println(counterFalse);
                counterFalse++;
                counterFalse=counterFalse+1;
            }

        }

        if (gameResult) {
            System.out.println("You Won");
            System.out.println("True:" +counterTrue );
            System.out.println("False:" +counterTrue );

        } else {
            System.out.println("You Lost");
            System.out.println("True:" +counterTrue );
             System.out.println("False:" +counterTrue );
        }

    }

    }
```

Let me know if you have any questions